# endTurnWithNextParticipant deprecation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Thought I fixt my problem with the deprecation, I now found out I haven't. My game is not functioning correctly.

In the new endTurnWithNextParticipant there is also a timeout for the next player (the timeinterval they have to answer on there turn) I have set that on 86400 (seconds in a day)

However the game doesn't send a turn at all anymore, I can set the second to for example 1 then it would send the turn but still later then it used to before the deprecation. even If I set the interval to 0.

I think the problem is that the turn is send to the player that has just send a turn.

this is the code: (the commented line is the what I used but is now deprecated)

```
[currentMatch endTurnWithNextParticipants:currentMatch.participants turnTimeout:86400 matchData:data completionHandler:^(NSError *error){
    //[currentMatch endTurnWithNextParticipant:nextParticipant matchData:data completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
            statusLabel.text = @"Oops, there was a problem.  Try that again.";
        } else {
            statusLabel.text = @"Your turn is over.";
            textInputField.enabled = NO;
        }
    }];
```

I hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `currentMatch.participants`, you may want to try

```
[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:nextParticipant,nil]
```

That way, the only player that's being sent is `nextParticipant`, the same way you had it in the deprecated code.